# Perl: Loop through months in a specified range

Tags: perl, date, datetime

I need to make a loop (foreach) for all the months specified in a range like:
  01-2013 to 09-2015 (month-year) format.
The tricky part is that in every loop i need the month - year data as well to run an sql query, so i cannot use a simple +1 counter.

I looked as Date::Calc and Date::Simple but it did not offer me a solution.
Does anybody have a code snippet i could use or come up with an idea on how to tackle this challenge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) module has a nice function [`add`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime#Adding_a_Duration_to_a_Datetime) which allows you to add whatever amount of time you want to an object:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;
use feature 'say';

my $start = DateTime->new(year => 2013, month => 1);
my $end   = DateTime->new(year => 2015, month => 9); 

while ($start <= $end) { 
    $start->add(months => 1); 
    say $start->strftime("%m-%Y"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to loop through the dates, why not just use this:

```
for my $year (2013..2015) {
    for my $month (1..12) {
        my $date = sprintf "%02d-%d", $month, $year;            

        # do your $date processing here
        ...

        last if ($date eq "09-2015");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Date::Calc](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date%3a%3aCalc) is awesome. Check it again

```
use Date::Calc();
my ($month, $year, $end_month, $end_year) = (1, 2013, 9, 2015);

while (($year < $end_year) || ($year == $end_year && $month <= $end_month)) {
    print "year: $year, month: $month\n";
    ($year, $month) = Date::Calc::Add_Delta_YMD($year,$month,1,0,1,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $start_date = '01-2013';
my $end_date = '09-2015';
my ($sm, $sy) = split '-', $start_date;
my ($em, $ey) = split '-', $end_date;

for my $y ($sy..$ey) {
  for my $m (1..12) {
    next if ($y==$sy && $m<$sm);
    last if ($y==$ey && $m>$em);

    # use $m and $y for further processing sql query
    # print "Month: $m\t Year: $y\n";
    # ...

  }
}
```